# Getting syntax error in ocaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am trying to make a module that would allow to create a table in ocaml. It would do a query called `project` to limit the table's values. However on the last line of the definition of the function chooser I am getting syntax error.

```
module type TABLE = 
sig
  type database
  type table 
  val create_table: string list * string list* (string list) list -> table
  val printTable : table -> string
  val listToString : string list -> string
  val project : string list * table -> table
  val chooser : string list * string list-> string list
end;;

module UsingTable : TABLE =
struct 
  type table = (string list * string list* (string list) list) 
  type database = table list
  let create_table (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)

  let chooser inputList = (    
    for i = 0 to (List.length trueFalseList-1) do
      if List.nth trueFalseList i = "True"
      then  
        (List.nth inputList i)::ans
    done
      List.rev ans;;)

  let project (conditions, aTable)= (
    let rec innerProc tmp= function
        n,[],v->List.rev tmp
      |n,cH::cT,v-> if List.mem cH conditions 
          then innerProc (["True"]::tmp) (n,cT,v) 
          else innerProc (["False"]::tmp) (n,cT,v) 
    in 
    let trueFalseList = innerProc [] aTable




    let rec finalListCreator = match aTable with
        n,[],[]->n,[],[]
      |n,cH::cT,[]->n,chooser cH ::finalListCreator cT,[]
      |n,c,h::t -> n,c,chooser h ::finalListCreator t

  )


  let rec listToString aList = match aList with
      [] -> ""
    | h::t -> "\t"^h^"\t"^listToString t


  let rec printTable aTable = match aTable with 
      [],[],[] -> ""
    | [],[],vH::vT -> "\n"^(listToString vH)^printTable ([],[],vT)
    | [],cH::cT,v -> "\t"^cH^"\t"^printTable([],cT, v) 
    | n, c , v-> "\n"^(List.hd n)^"\n\n"^printTable([],c, v)




end;;

let atable =UsingTable.create_table (["Student"], ["Id";"Name";"Gender";"Course"], 
                                     [["001";"Jim";"M";"AlgoDS"];
                                      ["002";"Linnea";"F";"Databases"];
                                      ["003";"Anna";"F";"C#"];
                                      ["004";"Abby";"F";"C#"];
                                      ["005";"Arthur";"M";"JavaScript"]]);; 
print_string (UsingTable.printTable atable) ;;
```

Comment: please provide the exact syntax error. Your 'chooser' functions makes use of `trueFalseList` and  `ans` which are never defined - I suspect this is the root cause of your syntax error.

Comment: On the line  "List.rev ans;;)" the word List is in red and it says syntax error: operator expected.

Comment: @PierreG. any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines have at least two syntax problems:

```
let chooser inputList = (    
  for i = 0 to (List.length trueFalseList-1) do
    if List.nth trueFalseList i = "True"
    then  
      (List.nth inputList i)::ans
  done
    List.rev ans;;)
```

First, the `for .. done` is one expression, and `List.rev ans` is another expression. You need a semicolon (`;`) between them.

Second, you should use `;;` only when you want the input up to that point to be processed. But here if you process the input at the `;;` you are missing a right parenthesis.

In my opinion, you should be entering `;;` only at the toplevel. The best way to think of this token is as an instruction to the toplevel. It's not part of normal OCaml syntax.

These are only the first two errors. There are quite a few other errors in the code. It might be good to add one function at a time to the module so you can concentrate on a few problems at a time.

**Update**

The environment you're using is a little bit extra complicated because it has an **Evaluate** button that asks to evaluate what you've typed so far. This makes the `;;` token much less useful.

It would be a good discipline to use this environment without using the `;;` token at all. Just click the **Evaluate** button when you want an evaluation.

The main trick is if you want to evaluate a statement (a unit-valued expression in OCaml) at the outer level, like say `Printf.printf "hello world\n"`. The usual idiom to avoid putting `;;` before this is to make it into a declaration like so:

```
let () = Printf.printf "hello world\n"
```

That is the one non-obvious idiom that people use when writing source code (where the `;;` almost never appears in my experience).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey! I use [this environment](https://try.ocamlpro.com/fun-demo/tryocaml_index.html#path%3Ddemo) to run my code. I am confused: is it a toplevel or not? what are the syntax differences between toplevel and not toplevel codes? The tutorials in ocaml .org are for toplevel or usual development?

Comment: That is pretty close to a toplevel environment. If you're typing expressions and an interpreter is evaluating them for you, that a toplevel environment. Other people call it a REPL (read/eval/print loop). That one is a little extra complicated because there is also an Evaluate button that makes the `;;` token less obviously useful. Anyway once you start to write a lot of OCaml code you almost always start using the compiler as with a more ordinary compiled language. The toplevel is still useful for testing things out as you go however.